# Retouch image to get a cartoon appearance

Tags: photoshop-effects

I work on an automated embroidery pattern generator which processes the input image into a series of PDFs showing the color of each pixel mapped to a specific type of yarn. Processing the original "real-life" image works good, however I've noticed that significantly better results are obtained if the original image looks like a cartoon.

Example: *(top - original, bottom - cartooned image)*
[image]

I a software engineer who known next to nothing about graphics. Can someone devise a series of steps (Photoshop or Affinity Photo) needed to transform one image into the other? Or is this a manual effort involving illustration work that couldn't possibly be done automatically?

Comment: Other than the obvious knife/apple swap, those pictures are not processed one from the other. They are different source images.

Comment: I would say there's most definitely manual work involved there.  However there are filters to make something look like an illustration, to highlight the details etc.  There's a free plugin called [G'MIC](https://gmic.eu/) that [works with Photoshop](https://imgur.com/QHsjmLu), Affinity Photo, GIMP, and Krita, etc. I'm not adding this as an answer because I don't know if it will give you a result that your software will work well with.